# What subnet mask to use for a virtual IP in pfSense

Tags: ip, subnet, pfsense

I have a subnet `192.168.0.0/24`.

I want to create a new virtual IP address (VIP) in pfSense at `192.168.0.2`.

What difference does it make what subnet mask I use for the VIP?

Should I set the VIP to `192.168.0.2/24` so it matches my subnet or to `192.168.0.2/32` since the VIP is just a single IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subnet mask must match across all subnet devices - it determines which destination addresses are 'on link', all others requiring a gateway to reach.

Most likely you cannot configure a /32 subnet mask as it would mean the host is all alone and can't even reach a gateway to go elsewhere.